# only want to show some of the text

Tags: php

I have a long text in my sql database, i want to show on one page, but on another page i only want to show the first 100 characters, and if i use this line of code it works fine:

```
echo substr($result['text'],0,100);
```

but my code looks like this, and i cant figure out how to put the code inside my code?

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="nyheder"; // Table name

$db = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);

$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
// $result[''], skriv navnet på det ønskede felt mellem ''
    echo 
    "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"text\">
        <tr>
            <td width=80% height=100%>".$result['overskrift']."</td>  
            <td>".$result['dato']."</td>
            </table><table>         
            <td>".$result['billede']."</td>`enter code here`
            <td substr=,0,100;>".$result ['text']."</td><hr>
        </tr>
    </table>";
    };

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this row :

```
<td substr=,0,100;>".$result ['text']."</td><hr>
```

By this:

```
<td>" . substr($result['text'], 0, 100) . "</td><hr>
```